# Segmentation Fault when running script with Python3

Tags: raspbian, python

I have an application which should running on Python3 with Kivy and Postgresql.

I had my Python3 installed according to the guide from this blog below:

[Install Python3](https://bohdan-danishevsky.blogspot.com/2017/01/building-python-360-on-raspberry-pi-3.html)

but I realize the Python 3.7 was installed in /home/pi/Python-3.7.2 instead of inside /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.

I had run the command below to install it in /usr directory

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 2
```

then I point my python back to Python2 with command below:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Then, I run my python application with Python3 as below:

```
python3 script.py
```

I get segmentation fault

However, if I run it with default python2, the apps able to launch. Does anyone know how can I solve the segmentation fault issue?

Comment: That command will not install ANYTHING.  It will just break python2

Comment: what do you mean break python2? i thought it is install the python 3.7 into the /usr/bin directory

Comment: You continue to fiddle with update-alternatives and try to setup python to point to python 3.7. I am not an expert with update-alternatives, but that like looks like nonsense. **YOU DO NOT NEED IT** - if you install properly python 3 should just work.

Comment: In addition to the comments by @Milliways, the most recent version of Raspian comes with Python 3 installed already, although it's 3.5 rather than 3.7 according to what I have on my (updated) system right now.  You may be better off upgrading your distribution overall.

Comment: Separately from the installation, the simplest answer to your question seems to be to run it with the default `python2` since you said that works and you haven't given any details about the nature of the segmentation fault or why this is not adequate.

Comment: HI  Brick and Milliway, I already changed back the default python to python2, I run my application with python3 script.py but it still giving me segmentation fault. the error message is not showing any other info apart from segmentation fault. The reason that I need to run with Python3 is because there is certain issue with apps which if I am running in Pycharm and point to Raspberry Pi Python 3.7, those issue is not occur. For your information, this application is using Kivy and Postgre as well